# Подслушивание копирование email

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня. Пытаюсь отслеживать копирование email, но не получается. Для этого я в код страницы с счетчиком метрики вставляю скрипт:

```
  $(".email-header").bind('copy', function() {
   console.log("1");
   ym(88888888,'reachGoal','email_copy');
   return true;
  });
```

Ниже по коду HTML страницы находится email:

```
<div class="emailcont">
    <img class='email-icon' src="../img/emailicon.png">
    <div class="email-header" id="email-header">email</div>
</div>
```

В метрике я создал цель - JS событие, где Идентификатор цели: совпадает с email_copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт, который ты предоставил, должен работать. Вот несколько возможных причин:

Убедись, что код находится внутри блока $(document).ready(function() {...});, чтобы гарантировать, что скрипт будет выполняться после загрузки страницы.

Проверь, что идентификатор цели, указанный в коде метрики (88888888), совпадает с реальным идентификатором метрики.

Убедись, что код метрики правильно установлен на сайте и активен для отслеживания событий.

Стоит отметить, что использование события **copy** может быть ограничено в некоторых браузерах из-за соображений безопасности. Возможно, браузер блокирует выполнение твоего кода из-за таких ограничений. В этом случае, тебе может потребоваться найти альтернативный подход для отслеживания копирования email-адреса, например, добавление обработчика кликов на сам email-адрес.

```
$(".email-header").on('click', function() {
   console.log("1");
   ym(88888888,'reachGoal','email_click');
   return true;
});
```

В коде использовал метод on() вместо bind(), так как on() является рекомендуемым методом в более новых версиях jQuery.

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо за помощь! Наконец я увидел в консоли заветную цифру 1)))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".email-header").bind('copy', function() {
console.log("1");
ym(88888888,'reachGoal','email_copy');
return true;
});
});
```

Подозреваю, что вы не накидываете функцию при загрузке страницы

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо за помощь, но почему то не работает предложенное Вами решение.